# how to convert speech to text realtime from speaker output

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

i am trying realtime conversion of speech both from microphone and speaker outputs . Currently i am trying to record both the speakers call into a wav file and sent that to Cognitive SDK for conversion .

Is there a way to convert the output of the speaker device using cognitive sdk.
Link to any samples would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Microsoft Bing Speech API for this. Generate key and integrate this on your web page, it will convert  speech to text in real time.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/directory/speech/